# Weakening of open determinacy for uncountably long games

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, determinacy, infinite-games

For a cardinal $\kappa$ I'll use the phrase "$(\kappa,\kappa)$-game" to mean "two-player, perfect-information, deterministic game on $\kappa$ of length $\kappa$."

Say that a cardinal $\kappa$ is **LOI** *(= **l**imited **o**pen **i**ndeterminacies)* iff for every tree $T\subseteq\kappa^{<\kappa}$ the corresponding "$\kappa$-open" game $G_T$ has the property that there is a set $\Sigma_T$ of strategies for (at least) one of players $1$ and $2$ such that

- every strategy for the other player is beaten by some element of $\Sigma_T$, and
- $\vert \Sigma_T\vert<2^\kappa$.

*(To be clear, the game $G_T$ is the $(\kappa,\kappa)$-game in which on turn $\alpha<\kappa$ player $parity(\alpha)$ plays an ordinal $\beta_\alpha$, and player $1$ wins iff the sequence $(\beta_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ eventually leaves $T$.)*

LOI is a "near-determinacy" principle for (a not-too-small class of) games of uncountable length which is not *trivially* trivialized by the failure of determinacy for games of length $\omega_1$. For example, if $\kappa$ is inaccessible then recasting an undetermined game of length $\lambda<\kappa$ as a game of length $\kappa$ by just adding "dummy moves" does result in an undetermined game on $\kappa$ but does *not* result in a failure of LOI at $\kappa$.

I'm curious whether, in fact, this does trivialize:

> Question: is the existence of an uncountable LOI cardinal consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$?

Comment: In case it's useful, I have a tentative argument that the clopen version of LOI is equivalent to LOI itself, but I'm still checking the details.

Comment: Can we also say that $\kappa$ is LOL if the requirement for it to be LOI is ridiculous?

Comment: All $κ$ with $κ^{<κ}<2^κ$ satisfy this property since if player 2 (i.e. closed) does not have a winning strategy, then each strategy is defeated by some play, and there are $≤κ^{<κ}$ plays winning for player 1.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky Oh, yes, that's a good point.